# How to run actions on previously generated SpriteNodes in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making an app, where objects fall from the top of the screen. These objects are spriteNodes and are generated with the method `- (void)generateNodes`. When you tap on the screen a touchPointer node is created and detects if you touch the spriteNode. This is done with a didBeginContact method. I have the detection of the touch, however, when I try to add a death animation to the objects, there is a problem. If I tap an object and it begins its death animation, then I tap another object that has been newly generated. The death animation from the previous continues with the newly generated object. So, instead of starting the newly generated object's own death animation – basically fading out, it will continue the death animation from the previous object as that object finishes.

**Example:**

`firstObject` alpha when tapped 0.5 -> 0

== second object is tapped whilst firstObject is still running the death animation ==

`secondObject` alpha when tapped 0.2 -> 0

This is because when I tap the secondObject it continues the animation of the first object. I want to it to be where the secondObject starts its own animation, where it should start from an alpha of 0.5

Code of `didBeginContact`

```
if([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"object"] && [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"touchPointer"]){
        //Object Death Animation Actions
        int randObjectMovement = (arc4random()%2) + 1;

        touchedObject = [objects objectAtIndex:0];

        touchedObject.alpha = 0.5;

        if(randObjectMovement == 1){
            touchedObject.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
            [touchedObject.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-10, 18)];
            NSLog(@"Impluse completed");
        }else{
            touchedObject.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
            [touchedObject.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(10, 18)];
            NSLog(@"Impluse completed");

        }

        objectFadeOut = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.75];
        objectRemove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        objectDeathRotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI*2 duration:3];

        [touchedObject runAction:objectDeathRotation completion:^{
            NSLog(@"objectDeathRotation completed");
        }];
        [touchedObject runAction:objectFadeOut completion:^{
            NSLog(@"objectFadeOut and Removal completed");
            [touchedObject runAction:objectRemove];
        }];
    }
```

Code of `generateObjects`

```
- (void)generateObject{
    //Object Texture delcaration
    if ([self generateObjectType] <= 100 && [self generateObjectType] > 20){
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Object_N"];
    }else if([self generateObjectType] <= 20 && [self generateObjectType] > 5){
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Object_B"];
    }else{
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Object_G"];
    }
    objectTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    //Object Actions
    objectRotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI*2 duration:1];

    //Object Sprite declaration
    objectSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:objectTexture];
    objectSprite.position = [self generateObjectPosition];
    objectSprite.zPosition = 3;
    objectSprite.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    [objectSprite runAction:objectRotation];

    objectSprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:objectSprite.size];
    objectSprite.name = @"object";
    objectSprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = objectCategory;
    objectSprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory;
    objectSprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory | touchCategory;

    [objects insertObject:objectSprite atIndex:0];
    [self addChild:objectSprite];

}
```

By the way, objects is an NSMutableArray.

Please help!

Comment: Why do you add the object to the start of the `objects` array in `generateObjects`?

Comment: And this looks wrong: `touchedObject = [objects objectAtIndex:0];`.

Comment: @Droppy I thought, if I used a NSMutableArray I could target the specific sprite node that out have the actions ran.

Comment: Well lets talk about `touchedObject`.  How will it always be the first object in `objects` (i.e. the newest-created node)?

Comment: @Droppy every time a new object is created `[objects insertObject:objectSprite atIndex:0];` is used to always have the newest created object as the first in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the node from the contact:

```
SKSpriteNode *touchedObject = (SKSpriteNode*)contact.bodyA.node;
```

This gets the node involved in the collision and you can carry out the actions on it, no need for the array.

**Update**

Use local instances of the actions:

```
SKAction *objectFadeOutLocal = [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.75];
SKAction *objectRemoveLocal = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *objectDeathRotationLocal = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI*2 duration:3];
```

Comment: This works so that I no longer need the array. However, I still have the issue where each object is not starting its own new runAction. Thus, the problem continues.